# TemplateView in UI5 is not able to add id to rendered control

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to add IDs to my controls in a TemplateView so that my router will be able to reference them.

This is how my TemplateView looks like. I have three controls with unique IDs.

```
<div>
    {{control sap-ui-type="sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout" id="TopLeftNav"}}
    {{control sap-ui-type="sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout" id="BottomLeftNav"}}
    {{control sap-ui-type="sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout" id="MainContentNav"}} 
<div>
```

This is how the generated HTML looks like. The renderer has assigned generic IDs (__layout0, __layout1, __layout2) to the controls instead.

```
<div>
    <div id="__layout0" data-sap-ui="__layout0" class="sapUiHLayout sapUiHLayoutNoWrap"></div>
    <div id="__layout1" data-sap-ui="__layout1" class="sapUiHLayout sapUiHLayoutNoWrap"></div>
    <div id="__layout2" data-sap-ui="__layout2" class="sapUiHLayout sapUiHLayoutNoWrap"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make sure the renderer use the IDs that I have specified in my template?

Answer (score 0):

I just read about that in the SAP document "SAPUI5 Developer Guide for SAP HANA". UI5 does actually expand the developer written ID of controlls. One example: I have a SearchInput with the ID of "searchField" in a file named Master.xml.  The *actuall* ID in the html got changed to something similar like "Master--searchField". Try it out.

With the explanation above, I would answer it is not possible to get the ID 1:1.